# Load products for specific store Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, products

[image]

```
        $products = $this->productFactory->create()
                                ->setStoreId($store_id) //this is not working
                                ->getCollection()
                                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', '4')
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

I want products of Slovenian Website, not Main. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Try this**

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    .......................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    .......................................
)
{    
    .......................................
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    .......................................
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $storeid = 2; 
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addStoreFilter($storeid);        
    return $collection;
}
```